# Optional type annotation. Using value after checking if is None?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I was writing some code with type annotations in python. I have problem with Optional type. For example for a code like this:

```
maybe_number : Optional[int] =  ... # definition
if maybe_number == None:
    ...
else:
    # I know its int because i checked, but it is a typechecking error
    number : int = maybe_number 
    ...
```

I get error:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[int]", variable has type "int")
```

How can I express in python that I know actual type of value with Union or Optional type in certain branch. Do I need to check type in a specific way?

Answer (score 3):

Equality doesn't actually tell you much about an objects type, because the two objects could have `__eq__` methods that allow them to be equal but of different, even unrelated, types.  You can check if `maybe_number` *is* the value `None` by using identity comparison:

```
if maybe_number is None:
    ...
else:
    number : int = maybe_number
```