# Getting a variable of Python type T from an Optional[T]

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

Two python method are defined as:

```
   def function() -> Optional[ast.Module]:
      pass

   def something(t: ast.Module) -> None:
      pass
```

In a caller:

```
   var = function()
   if var:
     do_something(var)
```

The type-checker complains that I can't pass an Optional[t] to t. I imagine that there's some sort of casting mechanism, but it escapes me.

To be precise, this is a unit test and looks like:

```
    self.assertIsNotNone(var)
    do_something(var)
```

With respect to possible duplicate [Optional type annotation. Using value after checking if is None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641598/optional-type-annotation-using-value-after-checking-if-is-none),

```
new_var: ast.Module = var
```

gets the same type error.

Is an 'if' required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One has to explicitly exclude the case that the value is identical to None, not just any false’y value.

```py
var: Optional[...] = function()
if var is not None:    # reject None case in this branch
    do_something(var)  # `var` is the unwrapped type
```

The inverse is also possible:

```py
var: Optional[...] = function()
if var is None:    # handle None case in this branch
   ...
else:              # no more None case in this branch
    do_something(var)  # `var` is the unwrapped type
```

---

Note that type checkers cannot inspect arbitrary functions for type guards. An implicit rejection such as `self.assertIsNotNone(var)` is *not* equivalent to an explicit check against `None`. An additional, explicit exclusion is required.

```py
self.assertIsNotNone(var)
assert var is not None    # reject None case after this point
do_something(var)
```

Of course, it is always possible to [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) away the option. Since this disables verification for the variable type, it should generally only be a last resort.

```py
do_something(cast(ast.Module, var))
```